# Is it possible to use C++ code in an objective-c iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I'm thinking about writing an application that will have a web-version and an iPhone version (and perhaps later also an android version).

Since there is some algorithms that are the same on the iPhone and the web versions, I was wondering if it is possible to write that part in c++, while keeping the rest of the application in objective-c?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely. You can write in C and C++, as well as Objective-C. Your algorithms can easily be in straight C++.

Comment: imo you're probably also better off writing the algorithms in c++: suppose you want to reuse them later you won't be tied to objective-c

Comment: I was thinking of SO, but according to the P.SE faq, it allows questions on "Architecture", where SO is about "Specific programming problem, software algorithms, coding". I believe that this question falls in the first category.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as others have mentioned you can mix C and C++ in with ObjectiveC.  It's worth noting, though, that any code that makes of the Aqua GUI or Cocoa has to rely on Objective-C.  So, you could re-use existing business logic in C++ and "wrap" it with Objective-C.  I know a number of people have done this with existing game frameworks coded in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can also write Objective-C++ by changing the file extension from .m to .mm. Then you can mix C++ and Objective-C code in the same file. It makes it very easy for your Objective-C UI code to call your C++ backend code.